# NodeJS not receiving params

Tags: android, api, android-volley, backend

I'm trying to send a post to my backend API through volley with params inside of it but I don't receive anything in the backend

Android Method:

```
private void sendPayments() {
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(PaymentActivity.this);

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, clientCheckout, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onResponse: "+response);

            if(response.toString().contains("Successful")) {
                Log.e(TAG, "onResponse: Successful");
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "onResponse: Failed");
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onErrorResponse: "+error);
        }
    })
    {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            if(paramHash == null)
                return  null;
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            for (String key: paramHash.keySet()) {
                params.put(key, paramHash.get(key));
            }
            Log.e(TAG, "getParams: "+params);
            return params;
        }

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            return params;
        }
    };
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

and here is the backend code:

```
 router.post('/checkout', (req, res, next) => {
  var url_parts = url.parse(req.url, true);
  var query = url_parts.query;

  const nonceFromTheClient = query.nonce;
  console.log(req.params);
  console.log(req.query);
  console.log(query);

  gateway.transaction.sale({
  amount: "10.00",
  paymentMethodNonce: nonceFromTheClient,
  options: {
    submitForSettlement: true
  }
}, function (err, result) {
  if(err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    console.log(result);
  }
});
})
```

All logs in the backend return nothing! but the `Log.e(TAG, "getParams: "+params);` logs the data so the data exists but I don't know if its being sent and the backend can't read it or it's not sent from the beginning

Comment: Hi, does your backend API return anything when you fire the same POST request via Postman ?

Comment: @MoA yes as stated in `function (err, result)`